# Subset based on most frequent value

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Say I have the below dataset as a CSV file.

I want my output to be a CSV file which is a subset of this data based on only the data associated with the most frequent value in column B.

In the below example data, the most frequent value in column B is "1", however this will change and so I need my code to not be so specific.

```
A    B
!    1
@    1
#    1
$    1
%    2
^    3
&    2
*    4
(    5
)    2

In this example, I want my output to be a CSV file of:

A    B
!    1
@    1
#    1 
$    1
```

But since the most frequent value will change, I'm not sure what my code should be.

Any help you can provide will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Just to clarify - if I was to summarise what you are trying to achieve, you would: 1) find most frequent value in B; 2) discard all rows where B is not the most frequent value ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use [`mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html) to return the value that appears most often and then filter on that value:

```
df[df['B']==df['B'].mode()[0]]
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  !  1
1  @  1
2  #  1
3  $  1
```

And [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) can be used for the Nth most frequent value (starting with N=0 being the most frequent) :

```
df[df['B']==df['B'].value_counts().index[N]]
```

e.g. for N=1:

```
df[df['B']==df['B'].value_counts().index[1]]
```

Output:

```
   A  B
4  %  2
6  &  2
9  )  2
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! You are the best. I'm a new python user and am still learning.

Comment: What if I wanted the 2nd or 3rd most frequent values?

Comment: Updated my answer with how to filter on the Nth most frequent

Comment: Amazing, thank you again so much! Have a great weekend!

Comment: @AmieJohnson (and perl, you should both get a notification): Welcome to the both of you to [so]! Please try to use comments as intended, see [when not to comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment): while "Thanks!" is polite, it's noise for any future readers. If you like this answer, please upvote it (and accept it if it answers your question) and pay it forward by helping others if you can!